# How to use php __toString

Tags: php, oop

What are the uses of `__toString` in PHP?

For example I have a function such as (inside a class called person)

```
public function __construct($id, $name) {

       $this->id = $id;
       $this->name= $name;
  }
```

and

```
$person= new person("12","James");

$person->setDescription("Test Description");

$person->setImage("Test Image");
```

How can I use `__toString` to grab this data and print them on one line.

**For example:** *12 Test Description James Test Image*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__toString()` method is used if you try to echo an object instance rather than simply properties of that object. Normally that would throw an exception, but the to_string method defines a response

```
class person{
    public function __construct($id, $name) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name= $name;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->id . ' ' . $this->name;
    }
}

$person= new person("12","James");
echo $person;
```

The `__toString()` returns the value that will be echoed